# Django app does not work after Deploy when I used Pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas, deployment

I have a project and it works well when I run the project in pycharm
But when I deploy this project on the server, it has a problem
The problem is using pandas toolkits
It works well when I remove "import pandas as pd" from the files on the server, but when I use this toolkit, the project does not work
It should be noted that after Deploy, when this package is used in one of the files, the whole project does not work
I use Apache
The version of packages on the server and local is the same
Pandas version is 1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

1: Make sure Pandas is installed in your deployment environment.
2: If you are using shared hosting than perhaps they have some restrictions.